# Is Oracle free to download?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am a Java developer and currently I use PostgreSQL as the RDBMS. However, I would also like to learn Oracle. So can I download a latest version of Oracle (11g I guess) for free?

I found this link: [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linx8664soft-100572.html), and it seems that it is downloadable. However, I know that Oracle Server is proprietary. So how does that work?

Also, will there be PL/SQL along with the download of Oracle 11g?

Answer (score 16):

If you're really only looking to learn about the development side and have no interest in the administration or installation side at the moment, a quicker route might be to download a [prebuilt developer VM image for Virtualbox](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html). That can get you up and running very quickly, and you can connect to the DB running inside the VM from outside, so you can continue to do your development in your current environment.

The overview echos what others have said about licensing kicking in once you ship an application (but Oracle licensing is a quagmire, you'll need to talk to Oracle about it if/when you get past playing around):

> Learning your way around a new software stack is challenging enough
>   without having to spend multiple cycles on the install process.
>   Instead, we have packaged such stacks into pre-built Oracle VM
>   VirtualBox appliances that you can download, install, and experience
>   as a single unit. Just downloaded/assemble the files, import into
>   VirtualBox (available for free), import, and go (but not for
>   production use or redistribution)!

For experimenting it's ideal, in my experience. Of course, it's unsupported, but as you won't have a support contract anyway that's a bit of a moot point.

As David said, PL/SQL is integral to the database, not a separate component, so it is available in the VM image. You get some tools too, including SQL Developer, but you might have less friction running that natively and connecting it to the DB in the VM.

Comment: Yes, +1 for VM's. VirtualBox is great in general -- I use it for RoR/PostgreSQL development on Ubuntu. Easier than installing Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 12):

Of course you ought to study the license, but as I recall it is free to download and use for non-production purposes.

It includes all of the Option packs, and is not in any sense cripled, but patches will not be available as they would be if you had a support account.

Oracle XE is free to use in production environments, but has limited functionality and sizing.

Comment: Thanks David. What about PL/SQL ? isn't that also available with it ?

Comment: Yes, PL/SQL is integral to the database. If you're looking for something easy to install to learn with then I'd suggest Express Edition.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle is free for download and use in development environment. If you go to production and/or require support you must pay.

Comment: Is the Production version different from what we download from that link ?

Comment: No, but it might not have all the latest patches available to someone with a support account. For general functionality it's the same

Answer (score 3):

"is oracle free to download" ?
yes,most oracle come with a Developer License that allows you to use full versions of the products at no charge while developing and prototyping your applications, or for strictly self-educational purposes. `Unless otherwise specified, our technical support organization will not provide technical support, phone support, or updates to you for the programs licensed under this agreement.`

you can download `Oracle XE` which is free to use in production environments. it's right there are several limitation `(CPU Limitations, Installation Restrictions, Server user data and Server Ram limitaions)` but my office use that version too in production level :p

**will there be PL/SQL along with the download of Oracle 11g ?**

```
PL/SQL is not a stand-alone programming language; it is a tool within the Oracle programming environment. SQL* Plus is an interactive tool that allows you to type SQL and PL/SQL statements at the command prompt.
```

To run PL/SQL programs, you should have Oracle RBDMS Server installed in your machine which will take care of executing SQL commands.

just download Oracle XE i mention before

Answer (score 0):

Yes for study purpose its free, you can download it form oracle site but you cant use it for commercial purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its free to download and use (for non-production).