# Is Oracle 12g free to download for learning purposes?

Tags: sql-server, oracle-12c

I am a software developer that supports and develops an application that connects to both Oracle databases and SQL Server databases.

I want to learn more about database administration.  Therefore I am planning to purchase SQL Server Developer edition and install it on my PC at home (it costs around: £60).

I am also planning to download and install Oracle 12C: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html.  I believe it is completely free to do this after reading the license agreement (assuming that I do not use if for commercial purposes i.e. I use it for learning purposes only).  Is that correct?

I have read many questions on here stating that previous versions are free e.g. this one: [Is Oracle free to download?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50158/is-oracle-free-to-download).  However, I want to make sure that it is free? - the questions I have read are a few years old at least.

Also when I register on the Oracle website; what do I put as my job title etc.  Is this the company I am employed by? - bear in mind that I am not downloading it for them - I am downloading it for me.

Comment: Licencing questions are off-topic here, but you seem to have got away with it :-). Personally, I consider **timely** (and accurate) licencing advice as being relevant to DBA work and nurturing the young grasshoppers of our trade is a "good thing". Regrettably voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licencing is off-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for learning, it is free.

[Software Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html)

> All software downloads are free, and most come with a Developer
>   License that allows you to use full versions of the products at no
>   charge while developing and prototyping your applications, or for
>   strictly self-educational purposes. (Unless otherwise specified, our
>   technical support organization will not provide technical support,
>   phone support, or updates to you for the programs licensed under this
>   agreement.) You can buy products with full-use licenses at any time
>   from the online Store or from your sales representative.

Filling the registration form:

[Terms of Use](http://www.oracle.com/us/legal/terms/index.html)

> 7. Security, Passwords and Means of Accessing the Site and Content
>
> If any of the Services require you to open an account, you must
>   complete the registration process by providing us with current,
>   complete and accurate information as required by the applicable
>   registration form.

Comment: Thanks.  With regards to the terms of use; I guess I should supply my current job title and employer name (even though I am not downloading it for them).  +1 for the links.

Comment: could you answer the question in my last comment? I should then be in a position to mark the question as answered.

Comment: @w0051977 --- if you're not using it for your work, then I wouldn't be telling them about your employment. If you're not "gaming" the system by not giving data which is none of their business, then I wouldn't feel morally obliged to give it. Neither would I feel legally obliged - IANAL, but as far as I know, this is moot - i.e. hasn't been tested in court. For the record, I completely support the right of those who produce software to charge what they like for it. AFAIC, Oracle has made it clear that for education, some sort of "fair use" applies. Your data is yours, not Oracle's.

Comment: @w0051977 I didn't want to write this in my answer, but here you go: I don't think anyone cares whether you fill in your real employer and job title, or just make up something, or put an X everywhere.

Comment: @BalazsPapp - indeed Bálazs, it seems that Oracle's attitude is that "if you're not making money, then we won't take money off you". If money changes hands, then you may well be obliged to provide data for legal contractual reasons, but if not, I'd leave well enough alone. I have to say, I have respect for Oracle's attitude in this regard - furthermore I have been critical of them on their own forums in the past (not a loon, just griping :-) ) and my posts were neither censored nor deleted. Just say you're "John Smith" working for "Acme corp." and you'll be fine.

Comment: I have already registered and I put my employers details as I am planning to use the product (installed on my PC at home) to become more productive at work.