# Is it free to download an Oracle Enterprise Edition image from Docker?

Tags: oracle, docker

I would like to learn more about Oracle (I am more of an SQL Server developer).  I am thinking about downloading the Docker image: https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition?tab=reviews

I am a developer and this is strictly for learning purposes.  I have read lots of other similar questions on here like this one: [Is Oracle free to download?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50158/is-oracle-free-to-download/50163) (dated 2013), however they are many years old.  One of the answers in the question I have posted a link to says: "strictly self-educational purposes".

The reason I am concerned is because before downloading the image you have to supply a company name i.e. it is a mandatory field.  There is no company because this is strictly for learning purposes and the reviewed comments on the Docker webpage are from "verified purchasers". I was thinking about downloading the express edition but some of the features I want to learn about are not available with the express edition.

Can I use the EE image for learning purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the official (example?) Docker image from Oracle.

Oracle has put many things on GitHub. Docker images are one of them.

https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase

---

Licensing questions are off topic for this site. But (AFAIK), for *educational purpose only*, you can use EE for free.

Comment: What is the benefit of downloading from github rather than Docker? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 Docker displays "The products on this page are no longer maintained, and will be removed in the future." Seems like Oracle does not provide docker images there any more.

Answer (score 2):

For educational and development purposes you can download and use the Oracle Database without a support contract. Without a support contract you don't have access to updates and patches. You don't want to go into production with a non-patched database.

You can download pre-built docker images from

https://container-registry.oracle.com

1. Create an account at [oracle.com](https://oracle.com). It is free.
2. Navigate to the https://container-registry.oracle.com and select the image you want to pull down.
3. Make sure you accept the Oracle Standard Terms and Restrictions (green checkmark)

Now you are ready for the bash-console!

```
cat ~/.oracle_password | docker login container-registry.oracle.com --username firstname.lastname@mydomain.com --password-stdin
Login Succeeded 
docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:latest
latest: Pulling from database/enterprise
35defbf6c365: Pull complete
b7267f7fbeee: Pull complete
...
```

You can also go to [github](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images) and build the images yourself. You will have to download the Oracle Database software and put them into designated folders before executing the build script.

Oracle Database 18c XE is full of EE feature. The community voted for this.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks.  I assume it is free to doenload from here as well: https://hub.docker.com/_/oracle-database-enterprise-edition ?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, you can download and use for educational and development purposes without a support contract. When learning the Oracle Database you start with their latest product - Oracle Database 19c no? Like there is now a rich support for JSON in 19c compared to 12.2.0.1